Entity Framework Core v8.0.8 issues moving the context and the migrations to a different library project
I'm facing some issues while moving the migrations and context to a different library projects with in the same solution.
We have an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API where the context and migrations are, is currently using SQL Server as the provider and the point of doing this is to be able to use other providers with Entity Framework Core like Mysql, PostgreSQL, etc.
I'm following this article from Microsoft on how to achieve this using a separate migrations project
This is the initial state of the project:
I started with my ASP.NET Core Web API project and at this point when I run the dotnet ef migrations add ... command, the migration that is created is empty, so there are no current changes in the models that would require database changes.
I went ahead and create the two library class projects webapi.data (for the context and the db models) and webapi.data.sqlserver (for the migrations for SQL Server).
My project structure looks like this now:
webapi
webapi.data
webapi.data.sqlserver

This is how my project references each other following Microsoft article
webapi ->  webapi.data
webapi.data.sqlserver -> webapi.data

In both webapi.data and webapi.data.sqlserver, I added references to the packages
EntityFrameworkCore (8.0.8)
EntityFrameworkCore.Design (8.0.8)
EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer (8.0.8)

and we use a DesignTimeDbContextFactory class in webapi.data where the context is build like this:
builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, cfg => cfg.MigrationsAssembly("webapi.data.sqlserver"));

Same when creating the context on the dependency injection in the webapi project.
Currently this is my state, but when I add migrations using the command
dotnet ef migrations add "some migration that should be empty"
       --context MyContext --project webapi.data.sqlserver

a new migration is added on the migrations folders in webapi.data.sqlserver with a lot of changes, basically changing string columns from being nullable to not nullable.
migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
     name: "name",
     table: "setup_report",
     type: "nvarchar(max)",
     nullable: false,
     defaultValue: "",
     oldClrType: typeof(string),
     oldType: "nvarchar(max)",
     oldNullable: true);

migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
     name: "code",
     table: "setup_report",
     type: "nvarchar(max)",
     nullable: false,
     defaultValue: "",
     oldClrType: typeof(string),
     oldType: "nvarchar(max)",
     oldNullable: true);

This is problematic in our case because we have this application deployed already with pretty large amount of data, in many cases the cardinality of the tables are on the tens of millions and applying this migrations could be quite heavy.
So not sure why this migration is being generated: initially there where no model changes that require DB changes and neither the models or the namespaces had change.
Any ideas of what is going on here?

Do you have a [mre] you can share? Can you please share it?
